# Interval callback is interrupting download callback in Dash. Is there a way to stop this?

Tags: python, django, plotly-dash

I have an app built using django-plotly-dash in a container. The app uses an interval callback to periodically check the container for new files that are added from a backend process and update the frontend with said files. There is also a callback to download the file from the container. I've noticed when downloading a file, the interval callback is hammering away and interrupting the download callback. When the interval callback is disabled, the download works fine.

I've disabled the interval callback and replaced it with a manual refresh button for the time being. It's currently satisfying the client's needs, but they would like it to automatically update instead of pressing "Refresh" until the files appear.
Can anyone point me in the right direction on how to go about this issue?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.